# Trying to put logo dead center of page gets worse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap so I'm still trying to figure out how it works.  I was trying to place my name in the dead center of the page. I used class specifically for the log to be placed in my selector was .logo and instead of of my "logo" being places in the center my "nav bar"(not finished yet) was placed in center along with my logo. Can anyone help explain what happened and how can I fix this please?

[image]

Comment: please put your code in fiddle or your questions.

Comment: Please add your html and css in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try these, whichever works for you

```
.logo {
    margin: auto 0;
}

Or

body {
    position: relative;
}
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```